# What does "only the best was good for you" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Elvira ... took something in her ... hand. It was a syringe and she
> was stricking it into the ... drip tube....
>
> What was that? Thomas asked.
>
> Atempted murder. Insulin. Her Long was meant to die of a hypoglycaemic
> coma...
>
> why did she do it?
>
> Ask her yourself....
>
> "you tried to kill him" Thomas said.
>
> "Who says so?" Elvira said.
>
> "I saw it. It's all recorded on tape  ."
>
> This jolted Elvira. "Her Long's room is filmed?"
>
> **"Only the best was good enough for you."**
>
> What does it show?
>
> you injecting something into the drip ...

I searched online dictionaries. Only I found [good enough for](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+enough+for) meaning. As a result, I didn't understand the sentence.

So, could you please explain it to me? What is the relationship between this sentence the before one?

- Note: Elvira is owner of a company, the head of the family and Thomas's mother.

From *Small World* by Martin Suter.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it’s likely that Elvira was paying for the hospital room in which the incident happened. She chose to pay for the best quality room the hospital had (which is why “Only the best was good enough for you”), but wasn’t aware that the services she was paying for included closed-circuit TV recording.

Comment: Your guess is correct. She's paying for the hospital room.